# CSS animation - prevent 'sliding' on rotate3d

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create the effect of an opening door in css.

The issue I'm having is that the part which rotates also slides along the y axis. A door has a fixed rotation point, which is not really working here.

How can I prevent this sliding and ensure that the right part of the div `.mover` stays fixed to the right of the div `.door`?

```css
.door {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.mover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.door:hover .mover {
  transform-origin: 100% 40%;
  transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="door">
  <div class="mover">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `transform-origin` to the base `.mover` selector, instead of the `.door:hover .mover` selector. Like this:

```css
.door {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.mover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform-origin: 100% 40%;
}

.door:hover .mover {
  transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="door">
  <div class="mover">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Solves it. For some reason I can't accept this, but I will once I can, thanks for the help!

Comment: Great. You have to wait a few minutes before a solution can be accepted.